# Updating embedded Kernel

Tags: kernel, u-boot

I've a System that starts a Linux-Kernel(3.9) by using u-boot(1.1.5).
Everything runs well when Kernels uImage got flashed with u-boot and tftp. I tried ti update the Kernel from within Kernel-prompt using:

```
flash_eraseall /dev/mtd2
nandwrite -p /dev/mtd2 /uImage
reboot
```

Selected Partitions are ok. While restarting u-boot shows the messege:

```
Loading from NAND 512MiB 3,3V 8-bit, offset 0x200000
   Image Name:   Linux-3.9.0
   Image Type:   ARM Linux Kernel Image (uncompressed)
   Data Size:    1897760 Bytes =  1.8 MB
   Load Address: 20008000
   Entry Point:  20008000
NAND read from offset 3c0000 failed 0
** Read error
Wrong Image Format for bootm command
ERROR: can't get kernel image!
```

mtd2 starts at 0x200000. How could I fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

Cancel booting from kernel so that you end up in U-boot. Once in, try:

```
# setenv bootargs root=/dev/mtd2 (or root=/dev/mtdblock2);
# setenv bootcmd 'bootm 0x200000 (or 0xc0200000)'
```

*Note the above two environment variables are set in addition to others which will be set as per your requirements.

Comment: The following is part of my configuration:
bootcmd=nboot 0x21400000 0 0x200000; bootm
bootargs=mem=64M noinitrd root=dev/mtdblock3 rw rootfstype=jffs2

rootfilesystem is saved on mtd3. The Problem occures in nandwrite. I checked the writen images, if I update with u-boot sere are some bits different to the original uImage. (This starts correct)
If I use nandwrite, the image gets dumped to the memory without this bits. (start fails).